# How to talk with an employer to get time to look for other opportunities

Tags: professionalism, job-search, job-offer

I got through the final stage with a company in Germany and they told me they got a very good impression of me, but they “need more time to clarify the budget available to hire me” and they “might be able to hire me in the beginning of February” (about 2 months from now).

The company also gave me a good impression, but my plans recently changed as I would like to try my luck in Canada and if I don’t try now my work permit will expire.

How can I talk to the company to keep a good relationship so that I could reach out to them again in a few months in case Canada goes wrong? Should I tell them about my plans to go to Canada and the work permit expiration matter or should I tell them in a more subtle way that I need time to think or to look for other opportunities?

Since the company mentioned starting to work in February and they didn’t show me any contract yet I guess I could leverage on this.

Comment: Welcome new user.  You must totally forget about this job.  It will never happen.  It's gone.   Good luck in your job search!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention that you have no contract from the employer in Germany yet. Hence, you are under no obligation to them, and have no obligation to tell them anything.

In other words, **you can and should continue pursuing any other opportunities you're interested in, up until the point at which you sign a contract accepting an offer.**

If they come back and make an actual offer, with a contract (or the intent to provide one), at that point you can evaluate the specifics and decide to accept the offer, or keep looking. But until that happens, *it's open season.* They may come back to you tomorrow, or in 6 weeks, or never. If you're seriously considering staying in Canada, there's no reason to spur them into action by giving them any info at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the job in Germany, so keep up the job hunt locally.

For the German company, reach out to them by email or phone, and tell them you are still interested and wanted to follow up.

Do this no more than once per week, once every two weeks is fine.  You want to maintain communication and create/maintain relationships with people at the company you are targeting.

While you do this, continue your Canadian efforts.  When you have a job offer and a start date in hand, you can address whether or not you want to go with the German company.

Answer (score 0):

The operative word in their answer to you isn't "February", it's "might".  In the world of job hunting, having a job is a binary option: You either have a "yes" or you have "not yes", which encompasses everything that is not specifically "yes", including "might".  Which is to say, "might" = "no".

All of which is a long-winded way of saying that you have no requirement or need to show any sort of loyalty or preference to this company in Germany.  If you want to go to/stay in Canada, then you can definitely do so.  If the German company comes back to you in 2 months, then great, you can choose to accept their offer or not at that time.

As for what to do for the time being:

1) You are not expecting to hear back from this company until roughly February.  Somewhere in early February, if you have not found a job yet, you could send them an email:

> Hey guys, I just wanted to follow up on our previous discussion; you mentioned you might be able to give me some more information about my application in February.  Well, now it's February, I'm still available, and I was wondering what the status of my application is.

Then you can see how they respond and go from there.

2) Others have suggested to email them every week or so in the meantime.  I would not do this.  If you would like to keep in contact with them to make sure they don't forget you, then you can send them an email over the holidays, like "happy new year, oh and by the way any news on my application?"  You don't have to send this email on or anywhere near Jan. 1; sending them an email halfway through January would be perfectly acceptable.  Sending them a weekly or even biweekly email might be annoying; they've already told you they won't have news until February, so don't bug them.

3) If you find a job in the meantime, you do not have to notify the German company.  When/if they come back to you with an offer in February, you can simply respond something like "thanks guys, but I already found a job".  They are not expecting you to sit on your hands for 2 months, so such a response should not come as any surprise or shock to them or hurt your chances with them in the future.